# How would you access an element in a nested hash/array given a path like "a.b.0.x"?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a nested hash/array such as:

```
target = {
  :a => {
    "b" => [
      {
        :x => "here"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

where a hash key is never a number. Given a string of indices/keys separated by `"."` such as `"a.b.0.x"`, which would express `target[:a]["b"][0][:x]`, how can I access the corresponding element?

Comment: Question is not clear. How would you know if `a` part in the string is meant to be `:a` or `"a"`? How would you know if `0` is meant to be `0`, `"0"`, or `:0`?

Comment: I don't think this is good taste of coding.

Comment: @Daniel why is that? It’s e.g. perfectly valid for quick tuning of huge config. _As a user_, I definitely would thank a developer that provided an access to settings via dot notation.

Comment: @mudasobwa In the his/her code, some keys are symbols and some are string. Also, array is huge config is not good.

Comment: @Daniel: not sure what you're trying to say. Using ruby for configs is good. Indifferent access is good. Arrays are useful. Addressing values with dot notation is super-convenient. :shrug:

Comment: @sawa well I can guarantee it doesn't mean `:0` since that is not a valid symbol but I guess it could mean `:"0"` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
path = "a.b.0.x"

path.split('.').reduce(target) do |acc, val|
  case acc
  when Array
    break nil unless /\A\d+\z/ === val
    acc[val.to_i]
  when Hash
    next acc[val.to_i] if /\A\d+\z/ === val && acc[val.to_i]
    acc[val] || acc[val.to_sym]
  else break nil
  end
end rescue nil
#⇒ "here"
```

Comment: Given rails: `target.with_indifferent_access.dig(*path.split('.'))`. If indifferent access isn't needed, so is active_support.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev given tags specified Rails sucks (as usual :)

Comment: Ah, there are arrays too. In this case, your answer is  better, indeed.

Comment: Nitpicking: this code will fail to fetch value from `target = { "42" => 'the answer'}` :)

Comment: might want to note that a `Hash` can have `String` keys that are numeric values so this is case specific to the provided `Hash` and @SergioTulentsev beat me to it

Comment: @SergioTulentsev fixed.

Comment: Yes, type check is better. I was about to point out another failing case :)

Comment: Oh, come on. Use that sexy threequals :) `case acc when Array`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev as you wish :-P

Comment: @mudasobwa Not quite what I meant, tho :) This is: https://gist.github.com/stulentsev/a7c11c7be8fc2a9646d39b4a7cc6e42c

Comment: @SergioTulentsev since we are having fun pointing out flaws (more specifically in the request than the implementation) a `Hash` can contain numeric keys as  well e.g. `{42 => 'the answer'}` which would be unhandled by `val` or `val.to_sym` and `String#to_i` will return `0` when not lead with a numeric so `{a: {'b' => [{x: 'here'}]}}` will have the same return for `'a.b.0.x'` as it would for `'a.b.c.x'`

Comment: @engineersmnky fixed :)

Comment: @engineersmnky: good point about arrays and non-numeric path segments. The current version is too forgiving, I think. If it were me, I'd rather prefer loud crash when I try access array element by index `'foo'`, because this means that my expectations about data shape are wrong. But maybe I'm just making these requirements out of thin air. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I follow ruby default behaviour: both `{}[:inexisting]` and `[][0]` return `nil` rather than crash loudly.

Comment: @mudasobwa: but `[]['0']` crashes. So does `[]['foo']`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev nah, probably you’re right, but I am tired editing this answer :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: yeah, no pressure :)

Comment: @mudasobwa No problem I got you :)

Answer (score 2):

Given the edge cases for such access I would recommend creating a new class to handle this situation and homogenize the input into a consistent structure. In this case a `Hash` (probably still more edge cases *comments welcome*)

```
class DepthAccessor
  class AccessFailure < StandardError
    def initialize(val,current=nil,full=nil,depth=nil)
      super(
        if full && depth
          "Failed to find #{val.inspect} for #{current.inspect}:#{current.class} in #{full.inspect} at depth #{depth}"
        else
          val
        end
      )
    end
  end

  def initialize(target)
    raise ArgumentError, "#{target.inspect}:#{target.class} must respond_to :each_with_object" unless target.respond_to?(:each_with_object)
    @target = homogenize(target) 
  end

  def path_search(path,sep: '.',raise_on_fail: true)
    split_path = path.split(sep) 
    split_path.each_with_index.inject(@target) do |acc,(val,idx)|
      begin
        acc.is_a?(Hash) ? acc[val] : raise
      rescue StandardError
        if raise_on_fail
          raise AccessFailure.new(val,acc,@target,split_path[0..idx].join(sep)) 
        else
          nil 
        end
      end
    end
  end


  private 

    def homogenize(val)
      case val
        when Array
          val.each_with_index.with_object({}) {|(v,idx),obj| obj[idx.to_s] = homogenize(v) }
        when Hash 
          val.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),obj| obj[k.to_s] = homogenize(v) }
        else
          val
      end
    end
end
```

When you create a new instance all keys are converted to `Strings` and all `Array` are converted to `Hash`es using the `index` as the `key`

Then usage as such

```
target = {
  :a => {
    "b" => [
      {
        :x => "here"
      }
    ]
  }
}

DepthAccessor.new(target).path_search('a.b.0.x')
#=> "here"
DepthAccessor.new(target).path_search('a.b.c.x')
#=> Failed to find "c" for {"0"=>{"x"=>"here"}}:Hash in {"a"=>{"b"=>{"0"=>{"x"=>"here"}}}} at depth a.b.c
```

[Full Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/UrbanFlamboyantKittiwake)

If reservation of `Array`s is a requirement then here is another example (with a few extra features) [Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/SmartExpensiveAlbino)